# OpenBSD serial I/O: -lpthead makes read() block forever, even with termios VTIME set?

Tags: serial-port, pthreads, openbsd

I have an FTDI USB serial device which I use via the termios serial API. I set up the port so that it will time-out on read() calls in half a second (by using the VTIME parameter), and this works on Linux as well as on FreeBSD. On OpenBSD 5.1, however, the read() call simply blocks forever when no data is available (see below.) I would expect read() to return 0 after 500ms.

Can anyone think of a reason that the termios API would behave differently under OpenBSD, at least with respect to the timeout feature?

EDIT: The no-timeout problem is caused by linking against pthread. Regardless of whether I'm actually using any pthreads, mutexes, etc., simply linking against that library causes read() to block forever instead of timing out based on the VTIME setting. Again, this problem only manifests on OpenBSD -- Linux and FreeBSD work as expected.

```
if ((sd = open(devPath, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY)) >= 0)
{
  struct termios newtio;
  char input;

  memset(&newtio, 0, sizeof(newtio));

  // set options, including non-canonical mode
  newtio.c_cflag = (CREAD | CS8 | CLOCAL);
  newtio.c_lflag = 0;

  // when waiting for responses, wait until we haven't received
  // any characters for 0.5 seconds before timing out
  newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
  newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

  // set the input and output baud rates to 7812
  cfsetispeed(&newtio, 7812);
  cfsetospeed(&newtio, 7812);

  if ((tcflush(sd, TCIFLUSH) == 0) &&
      (tcsetattr(sd, TCSANOW, &newtio) == 0))
  {
    read(sd, &input, 1); // even though VTIME is set on the device,
                         // this read() will block forever when no
                         // character is available in the Rx buffer
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using -pthread or -lpthread?

Comment: sorry i just saw the title again ;)

Comment: can you try on OpenBSD 5.2 that we switched to default rthreads? on my 5.3 system your example does not block. obsd/amd64.

Comment: Zeroing out the `termios` structure is not the proper method of initializing.  You should call `tcgetattr()`, and then *modify* the flags.  You are using a POSIX interface, and you should following their practices for portability.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html).  Also the arguments to `cfset?speed()` look bogus; the "baud rate" is not a numeric value but an encoded value.

Comment: The change to rthreads is apparently important -- the code works correctly on OpenBSD 5.2!
Also, I'll change the `termios` struct init so that it's calling `tcgetattr()` first, but I don't see what I could do to change the arguments to `cfset?speed()` -- there's no encoded value for 7812 baud in the termios header.

Comment: cool ;) i'm glad you got it working ;)

Comment: *"I don't see what I could do..."*  -- The [man page for cfsetispeed()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cfsetispeed) clearly defines the set of constants allowed for the baud rate.  The results are undefined for other values.  7812 is a nonstandard value for a baud rate; why are you using that value? There's also no guarantee that the baud-rate generator can accurately produce that oddball value.  The next time you compile that code or use it on different HW, the connection may not work!  IMO that is broken code, and not fit for release.  Get a 'scope, and measure the actual bit time and baud rate.

Comment: The baud rate of 7812 is absolutely necessary, as the software is communicating with a Lucas 14CUX ECU. This ECU runs a 1MHz clock with a clock divisor of 128 for the serial lines, producing a data rate of exactly 7812.5 bps. The software that I wrote to communicate with it is documented as requiring a USB-to-serial converter capable of nonstandard baud rates. I specifically recommend the FTDI FT232R. If there's anything broken here, it's the termios API, which artificially limits baud rate selection to those attainable by 16550 UART. I welcome any suggestions for cross-platform alternatives.

Comment: *"it's the termios API, which artificially limits baud rate selection to those attainable by 16550 UART"* -- Where does this misinformation come from, or are you making this up?

Comment: _Where does this misinformation come from ... ?_ -- The 16550-family UARTs are capable only of bitrates determined by submultiples of a legacy clock rate, resulting in 9600 bps, 19200 bps, 38400 bps, etc. In the "Line Speed" section of the GNU libc manual, which covers `cfset?speed()`: _"There is no portable way to represent any speed but these, but these are the only speeds that typical serial lines can support."_ Perfect portability is therefore not an option for me, but passing the bitrate as an integer literal works fine for BSD. If there is a better option, I would love to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the termios manpage:

```
 Another dependency is whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set by open() or
 fcntl().  If the O_NONBLOCK flag is clear, then the read request is
 blocked until data is available or a signal has been received.  If the
 O_NONBLOCK flag is set, then the read request is completed, without
 blocking, in one of three ways:

       1.   If there is enough data available to satisfy the entire
            request, and the read completes successfully the number of
            bytes read is returned.

       2.   If there is not enough data available to satisfy the entire
            request, and the read completes successfully, having read as
            much data as possible, the number of bytes read is returned.

       3.   If there is no data available, the read returns -1, with errno
            set to EAGAIN.
```

can you check if this is the case?
cheers.

Edit: OP traced back the problem to a linking with pthreads that caused the read function to block. By upgrading to OpenBSD >5.2 this issue was resolved by the change to the new rthreads implementation as the default threading library on openbsd. more info on [guenther@ EuroBSD2012 slides](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/eurobsd2012/guenther-rthreads/slide001.html)

Comment: I've found that my no-timeout problem is caused by linking against the pthread library (which I need.) I created a standalone test program with nothing more than the code shown above, and the timeout only works when I build it _without_ linking against pthread (regardless of whether I'm actually using any pthread devices.) Why would this be?